# React to nested state change in Angular and NgRx

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Please consider the example below

```js
// Example state
let exampleState = {
  counter: 0;
  modules: {
    authentication: Object,
    geotools: Object
  };
};

class MyAppComponent {
  counter: Observable<number>;
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
    this.counter = store.select('counter');
  }
}
```

Here in the `MyAppComponent` we react on changes that occur to the `counter` property of the state. But what if we want to **react on nested properties** of the state, for example `modules.geotools`? Seems like there should be a possibility to call a `store.select('modules.geotools')`, as putting everything on the first level of the global state seems not to be good for overall state structure.

**Update**

The answer by @cartant is surely correct, but the NgRx version that is used in the Angular 5 requires a little bit different way of state querying. The idea is that we can not just provide the key to the `store.select()` call, we need to provide a **function** that returns the specific state branch. Let us call it the stateGetter and write it to accept any number of arguments (i.e. depth of querying).

```js
// The stateGetter implementation
const getUnderlyingProperty = (currentStateLevel, properties: Array<any>) => {
  if (properties.length === 0) {
    throw 'Unable to get the underlying property';
  } else if (properties.length === 1) {
    const key = properties.shift();
    return currentStateLevel[key];
  } else {
    const key = properties.shift();
    return getUnderlyingProperty(currentStateLevel[key], properties);
  }
} 

export const stateGetter = (...args) => {
  return (state: AppState) => {
    let argsCopy = args.slice();
    return getUnderlyingProperty(state['state'], argsCopy);
  };
};

// Using the stateGetter
...
store.select(storeGetter('root', 'bigbranch', 'mediumbranch', 'smallbranch', 'leaf')).subscribe(data => {});
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`select`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v5.0.0/modules/store/src/store.ts#L25-L69) takes nested keys as separate strings, so your `select` call should be:

```
store.select('modules', 'geotools')
```